# MuxerError in pymedia

Tags: python

so i have this code and when i run it i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tryer.py", line 7, in <module>
    da=dm.getInfo()
MuxerError: The header has not been read yet. Cannot get stream information.
```

-

```
    import glob
    import pymedia
    for x in glob.glob('C:\Downloaded/*mp3'):


        dm=pymedia.muxer.Demuxer( str.split( x, '.' )[ -1 ].lower() )
        da=dm.getInfo()
        print da
        a=da('title')
```

Please help

Comment: I found that published example programs on pymedia.org did not work (nowhere close in fact) against the CVS tip.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that the file must explicitly be opened ?

```
 f= wave.open( 'YOUR FILE NAME', 'rb' )
```

I'm not sure, but please try.